# updating table to the conditions listed

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to update a table by setting the ordercount to 1 with the following conditions but not sure how can I do it.

Table structure:

```
SalesOrderNumber             nvarchar(10)
SalesOrderNumberLineKey      int
StoreKey                     int 
TerminalNumber               nvchar(10)
OrderCount                   int
```

Please see the table below:

[image: Table1]

I want to update the OrderCount to 1 based on distinct SalesOrderNumber as shown in table.

As you can see,

SalesOrderNumber 1 has same storekey and terminal number so OrderCount = 1

SalesOrderNumber 2 has just one order so Order Count = 1

SalesOrderNumber 3 has same storekey but different terminal numbers so Total OrderCount =2

SalesOrderNumber 5 has one storekey as 21 and another two  as 34, so Order Count for storekey 21 = 1

OrderCount for storekey 34 = 1 (As terminal number is same)

Comment: expected output should be..

Comment: its the ordercount column as output ... setting it to 1 or 0

Comment: can u show your total output in text ..@shivang